# How to remove the automatic generation of line DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that after entering all the information in it.   It always generates an automatic line, worthless.

How can I remove that line there? Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm great, it's Friday!

Comment: Nice ! good for you (:

Comment: And to answer the rest of the question, more details are needed to understand what you are asking.  It'd be nice to have more info or even a picture

Comment: Check out the CellBorderStyle propery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the **AllowUserToAddRows** property of the DataGridView to **False** and you're done.
[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows.aspx)